# Delete all documents in Library

Tags: library, delete

I recently created a Sharepoint site (Record Center) for making a hiring portal. But I have an issue.

I am unable to delete all documents in one go from "default" library (renamed Job Applications).

1) I tried creating a workflow also, it did not work for me.

2) The only option left with me was deleting one by one (which is quite painful)

So, I cannot delete all files from default folder (Job Applications) but I can do the same in other Libraries created by me (because multiple selection of files is allowed there, like "Shortlisted Applications")

.enter image description here 
[image] 
[image]

Comment: multiple select option is missing in default library(Job Applications)

Answer (score 1):

thank you for all solutions. 
Well finally I was able to resolve the issue. 
The way I resolved is,q I create a new View and I got the option of multiple select ("Checkbox"). 
It worked and I was able to delete hundreds of documents in a single go.

thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Click on Modify view. Go to Tabular View section. Check : 
*Allow individual item checkboxes*

Comment: thanks Nadeem, but this doesnot work with this Default Library, "Allow individual item Checkboxes" option was by default checked (I re-checked and tested, still no success).

Comment: Checboxes and Inline editing both works in other libraries but not this default one :-(

Comment: Maybe some of the files are checked out or Approval Status is pending. Check-in the files which are checked-out and try to delete them or select only checked-in files and try to delete.

Comment: thanks Shantha, but the question here is how to select multiple files, the checkbox (for selecting files) is missing even after we enable the feature (as discussed above). Check-in and Check out concept is also applicable but 90% ofthe files are uploaded by me (I am Admin and developer).

Comment: @umesh, perhaps the page has been customised?